# Missing (can't find) Folder path configuration settings for Workspaces

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just updated VSCode and I can no longer find the folder path settings for my workspace.

After the update, I'm defaulted to the "GUI" version of settings, and I don't know where you setup the folder path to the folders in the left pane.

There was a configuration file, and I could set the path there.

Anybody know where it is?

```
Version: 1.35.1 (system setup)
Commit: c7d83e57cd18f18026a8162d042843bda1bcf21f
Date: 2019-06-12T14:30:02.622Z
Electron: 3.1.8
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.14393
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, you have to open & edit the *.code-workspace" configuration file associated with the workspace itself. :(